# run startFabric.sh without latest fabric-couchdb image

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying to write my first application with hyperledger.
I am running on `Windows 10 pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 15063)`.
I have followed the prerequisites below and have installed all the appropriate dependencies from the guide: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html.

I am able to use the out of the box scripts `./byfn.sh -m generate` to set up my first network.

While trying to execute the script (`./startFabric.sh`), I get the error

```
# don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
Removing network net_basic

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d ca.example.com 
orderer.example.com peer0.org1.example.com couchdb
Creating network "net_basic" with the default driver
Pulling couchdb (hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:latest)...
ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:latest not found
```

So I got to https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-couchdb/
and see that there is no latest tag for fabric-couchdb image
and I download successfully:

`docker pull hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:ppc64le-1.0.2`

```
 Status: Downloaded 
newer image for hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:ppc64le-1.0.2
```

but I am still receiving the same error

```
ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:latest not found
```

even though I can see with `docker images` that I do have the  fabric-couchdb image

```
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            
CREATED             SIZE
hyperledger/fabric-ca          latest              7e53be14f804        3 
weeks ago         238MB
hyperledger/fabric-ca          x86_64-1.0.2        7e53be14f804        3 
weeks ago         238MB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb     ppc64le-1.0.2       3a7f22fa9375        3 
weeks ago         1.61GB
```

Is there a way I can get the `startFabric.sh` to execute properly without the latest couchdb tag?

Comment: still facing same issue on ubuntu 16. did you solve this?

Comment: No, unfortunately I have not.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem.

In "~/abric/fabric-samples/basic-network/docker-compose.yml", in the couchdb section, change the line:

```
image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
```

to

```
image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.6
```

This is because Docker automatically pulls the latest image if no specific tag is provided.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a couple of days back on Ubuntu 16! Unfortunately, I missed a step "[Download Platform-specific Binaries](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/samples.html)" in the setup process which didn't installed few required tools like Cryptogen.

- Install the tools using the command `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/v1.0.6/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.0.6`
- Set the path to the bin directory of the installation folder `export PATH=<path to download location>/bin:$PATH`

Hope it works for you

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you've got a wong edition of hyperleddger/fabric-couchdb, the ppc641e-1.0.2 should go to x86_64-1.0.2. Once right, you can call docker tag to tag it be latest.